# Python behavior in loops

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I have the following code:

```
a = ['bobby', 'freddy', 'jason']
b = ['pep', 'lin', 'cat']

for a in b:
     for b in a:
          print a,b
```

I'd assume that after the first iteration of the outer loop, since the global variable `b` has been modified, and is now a `str` of length 1, the iteration would stop. But it doesn't do so.

Output:

```
pep p
pep e
pep p
lin l
lin i
lin n
cat c
cat a
cat t
```

So the basic question is, when the for loop is created, does it store a copy of the iterator and then loop through that even if the original variable now "points" to a different value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when the for loop is created, does it store a copy of the iterator and then loop through that even if the original variable now "points" to a different value?

Yes! You identified it correctly. Typically, when such looping constructs occur, the interpreter calls [`iter(object)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) and uses the returned iterator object for iteration. It does not matter if the original variable name is bound to some other object post this step.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, you can think of the *iterator protocol*, which controls the for-loop, to work like the following Python code:

```
iterator = iter(collection)
while True:
    try:
        x = next(iterator)
        # do something
    except StopIteration as e:
        break
```

Thus, the above code is the equivalent of:

```
for x in collection:
    # do something
```

For any given object, the `next` built-in function calls the object's __next__ "dunder" method, and the `iter` calls __iter__. By implementing these methods in your class, you can control the way a for-loop behaves for your custom object. Note, the above code just serves to illustrate the behavior. It is not the actual implementation. This was taken from Matt Harris' *Intermediate Python Programming* from the *Treading on Python Series*.